# Stripe Contributions from an External Site

Tags: civicontribute, stripe

I'm about to set up Stripe as a Civi payment processor and was wondering, if we have other non-Civi sites that take donations (Stripe charges), will those automatically be imported as Contributions in Civi? I see that Civi sets up a Webhook for charges (charge.succeeded, etc). Will it attempt to bring in all Stripe charges, or only those that are made from a Civi event or contribution form?

I would love to be able to auto import all charges across all our sites/tools, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert on the Stripe interface, but I'm sure enough that the answer is 'No', Only contributions that arrived via a CiviCRM screen (event, donation, membership) will be recorded.

Comment: Yes. you would need to use Contribution Import to pull in other transactions

Answer (score 1):

In theory, it appears that this would be possible, using the "payout reconciliation" report, here: https://stripe.com/docs/reports/api

Might have to hire someone to implement it though, I'd ask https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/users/4159/matthew-wire
who is the maintainer of the extension.